# Custimize status bar the ubuntu GUI

Tags: 20.04, gui, ubuntu-gnome, customization, statusbar

Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

I want my status bar menu to show the connected Bluetooth devices without opening the settings, similar to what it shows for Wi-Fi.

[image]

Is there a way to program it? Any example starter projects and explanations would be helpful.

Answer (score -1):

I use Ubuntu 22.04 with Gnome 42.9, and the menu shows bluetooth device as wifi.
[image]

You can try to upgrade Ubuntu to 22.04 through Software Update (see image)[image] and then with:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade
```

Comment: I cant upgrade yet. I have some project dependencies on 20.04.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure there is any extension or other way to do this with Ubuntu 20.04